# What is this stuff in my faucet?

Tags: sink, clog

[image]About every week I notice a decline in water pressure at my kitchen sink. When I notice it i unscrew the faucet head and the screen is completely clogged with this gritty sand stuff.

Is this calcium? Is this dirt?

What do I need to do to fix this?

This issue is only a problem in the kitchen...there is some sediment in the other faucets and showers but i get this amount after a year or so.

Comment: Have there been any water line repairs in the area?

Comment: Im sure there have been they are building onto the neighborhood....but wouldnt that effect the whole house and not just one sink?

Comment: Not sure of your piping but maybe the kitchen faucet it the first one in line.

Comment: "About very week" starting when? When did the construction start?

Comment: Construction has been going on for 2+ years. Water pressure is low when its clogged then when i clean it..the pressure returns to normal.

Comment: You might try removing any screens or flow restrictors and let each faucet in the house, one at a time, blast full force for a minute or two to remove sand sitting in the pipes.

Comment: if it's calcium it will dissolve in vinegar - this may  take a few days, a stronger acid will be faster.  sand will not dissolve in acid.

Comment: which pipe is it coming from? remove the screen as run hot water at full speed through a fine seive, see if you collect any particles,  then try the same with cold water.  each time run enough water to fill the sink several times.

Comment: So - municipal water system (not a well you own.) If it's coming in from the municipal pipes, one approach is a whole-house filter - I use one on my well to catch/remove occasional particulates / "sand" (not really sand in that case, more like left over rock flakes and newly precipitated manganese particles.) You'd still want to flush out your pipes where some has probably settled, and your piping layout might influence why the kitchen sink gets most of it.

Comment: Have you drained your water heater recently? It should be flushed once per year (as per manufacturer guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like mineral deposits. I'D just leave the aerator off for a few weeks, until the local builders stop messing with water pressure.